# How to access the selected text/value of a Kendo UI Grid DropDown-Editor?

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid with editable fields. If I add a new record I see the selected entry as [object Object]. But what I want is the "text" of the entry. How to achieve this?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Kendo UI Grid DropDown-Editor: How to access the selected text/value?</h3>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
       function nameDropDownEditor(container, options) {
           $('<input data-text-field="nameText" data-value-field="nameValue" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
               .appendTo(container)
               .kendoDropDownList({
                   dataSource: [
                       { nameText: "Jane",  nameValue: 100 },
                       { nameText: "Mike",  nameValue: 200 },
                       { nameText: "Harry", nameValue: 300 }
                   ],
               });
       }

      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
          { field: "id" },
          { field: "name", editor: nameDropDownEditor },
          { field: "age" }
        ],
        dataSource: [
          { id: 3030, name: "Jane", age: 30 },
          { id: 5353, name: "Harry", age: 53 }
        ],
        editable: "popup"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This screenshot shows the result after a selection:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFuhd.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the dropdown an id and binding to the save event:

...grid markup

```
.Events(events => events.Save("Grid_Save")
```

and in the save event

```
function Grid_Save(e) {
    var nameValue = $("#dropdownName").data().kendoDropDownList.value();
      //do something with the value
}
```